# Command line tool for parsing JSON input for Unix?

Tags: linux, command-line, parser

I'm looking for tool which would allow me to parse JSON from a pipeline. Like converting it to some other common formats which are easier to parse or sort or to retrieve certain elements (like XPath).

Comment: Related: [Unix command-line JSON parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3858671/55075) at SO

Comment: JQ is the tool....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ["json" tool](https://github.com/trentm/json#readme) I found is very flexible.

> `json` is a fast CLI tool for working with JSON. It is a single-file node.js script with no external deps (other than node.js itself).

Example usage:

```
$ echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | json foo
bar

$ echo '{"fred":{"age":42}}' | json fred.age    # '.' for property access
42

$ echo '{"age":10}' | json -e 'this.age++'
{
  "age": 11
}
```

Docs/features at http://trentm.com/json/

---

A list of alternative tools is also given at the bottom which 
are:

- jq: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/
- json:select: http://jsonselect.org/
- json-command: https://github.com/zpoley/json-command
- JSONPath: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/, http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/Javascript
- jsawk: https://github.com/micha/jsawk
- jshon: http://kmkeen.com/jshon/
- json2: https://github.com/vi/json2

Comment: Can you add some information about why this would be a good tool for the OP - especially if the conversion is possible? We like more than just link-only answers on SE sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pythons](http://python.org) supplied [JSON Library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse into python objects and then output in a variety of other formats also supported either by the python library or by additional libraries.  These include XML/xpath.